# If the first half of the sentence is a hypothetical scenario and other half is the postulated outcome, should one use "had been" or "was"?

Tags: tenses, sentence, sequence-of-tenses

Apologies for possibly a dumb question.

> Let's be honest, IF it was the other way around the build would have been
> blocked and if by any chance it **was** released, it would have caused
> some serious issues.

> Let's be honest, IF it was the other way around the build would have been
> blocked and if by any chance it **had been** released, it would have
> caused some serious issues.

**Context**
The build was actually released in a particular way. I'm trying to write if the build was deployed in a different way (This is what I mean by "other way around" in above sentence)

What confusing me is in a hypothetical scenario the build was blocked but in reality it wasn't so using **was** in the next sentence feels wrong? The same ways **had been** feels wrong because it was actually released.

Comment: What has  "actually happened" in your sentences? There are just two If-clauses.

Comment: @TimR A version of a build was deployed. This actually happened.

Comment: But it didn't happen *in the sentence*.   An *if*-clause is never an assertion of fact.  And if you speak of something known to have happened as if it might have happened, in the world of your sentence, it is not a fact but a possibility.

Comment: It's fine to have two had been's. But this question belongs on ELL, not here. Cheers.

Comment: Are you interested in grammar or what's nice prose style? Either is OK, IMO. It's a situation where past perfect is optional but not mandatory. You can divide it into 2 halves and treat each separately. If you think it's awkward, rewrite it, but that has nothing to do with whether it's grammatical, and we don't give writing style advice here.

Comment: It is unclear whether **(1)** the two parts of the sentence (before and after *and*) are independent, or **(2)** or the second part comes 'on top' of the first one (i.e. we are to consider the conditional of the second part only in the situations in which the conditional of the first part is actualised). If (1), the first part of the sentence is irrelevant to the question; if (2) is what is meant, that should be made clearer witiin the sentence.

Comment: If the sentence were a loose meat sandwich, you'd need a fork… I'd rework it.

Answer (score 0):

Fools rush in…

…but in my opinion neither sentence is grammatically correct. It seems to me that the problem here is the tense (or more generally timing) of the hypothetical conditions, and perhaps not realizing that there are **two** hypothetical conditions (requiring the same form), and a consequence (requiring a different tense).

The two hypothetical conditions are 1. the situation being reversed, 2. the consequences in that case.

The two possibilities for tense/timing are in the past or in the present.

**Hypothetical present**

The formal English would use the subjunctive, e.g.

> if it **were** the other way round… if it **were** (to be) released…

but this must be followed by the conditional

> it **would cause** serious problems

serious problems

However it is much more common to avoid the subjunctive, as the poster appears to be doing, e.g.

> if it **was** the other way round… if it **was** (to be) released.

this would be followed by the same conditional as with the subjunctive — only the subjunctive needs to be (or can be) changed:

> it **would cause** serious problems

**Hypothetical Past**

This does *not* use the subjunctive, but the pluperfect:

> if it **had been** the other way round… if it **had been** released.

which is followed by conditional perfect:

> it **would have caused** serious problems

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

> If I had eaten the last cookie, I would remember doing so.
>
> If I ate the last cookie, I would remember doing so.

In American English, "ate" is the more colloquial version, but the two sentences are used for the same scenario.

**Did you, or did you not, eat the last cookie?**

> I don't think I did. If I had eaten the last cookie, I would remember doing so.
>
> I don't think I did. If I ate the last cookie, I would remember doing so.

Besides, if I were going to eat the last cookie, I'd ask you if you wanted it.

Besides, if I was going to eat the last cookie, I'd ask you if you wanted it.

Whether or not I ate the last cookie, I can still make statements that treat it as conditional. If you know you did eat the last cookie, *and want to express that as a fact*, you don't use an "if" clause.

Answer (score 0):

**Had been** is the choice.

Pragmatically, (i) "had been" obviates any controversy about whether the subjunctive is needed and (ii) the past perfect is used for context and background.